# xml2: xml_text() returns different values depending on whether it's run manually

Tags: r, xml, xpath, stringr, xml2

I'm currently working on a project where I apply text mining to large numbers of xml files. I'm using the xml2 package to handle xml and the stringr package to handle most text mining tasks.

I'm running into a strange problem. Some of the xml documents contain weird space characters that screw up functions, so I need to replace these space characters with normal space characters first. To do this, I take all nodes from an xml document apart, extract the text, change it, then assign the changed strings back to the nodes, like this: `xml_text(node) <- str_replace_all(xml_text(node), "[:space:]", " ")`, which is successful at changing the space characters. This is a simplified version of my code:

```
# required libraries
require(xml2)
require(stringr)

testfunctie <- function(xmlstring)
{
  # turn string into xml nodeset
  data<-read_xml(xmlstring)
  # take every node separately
  data<-xml_find_all(data, "//*")
  browser()
  # replace weird space characters by regular ones
  for (i in 1:length(data))
  {
    xml_text(data[[i]]) <- str_replace_all(xml_text(data[[i]]), "[:space:]", " ")
  }
  # find all nodes containing a certain text
  tree <- xml_find_all(data, "//dossiernr[text()='ExampleText']")
  browser()
  return(tree)
}

# XML example
exampleXML<-"<dossier>
<dossiernummer>
<dossiernr>ExampleText</dossiernr>
</dossiernummer>
<titel>AnotherPieceOfExampleText</titel>
</dossier>"

mvt <- testfunctie(exampleXML)
```

Usually this works as it should, but in some cases a strange problem occurs, and the text extracted via xml_text() contains text from other nodes as well. You can see this by running the code above. When the first browser() statement triggers, select the remaining code up until the second browser() statement (lines 13-18) and run it manually. The object "tree" will then be a list of length 1, because the xml_find_all() function has found the node named "dossiernr" (the third node in the nodeset "data"), because the text inside this node is "ExampleText". You can verify this by typing `xml_text(data[[3]])` in the console, which is equal to `xml_text(tree[[1]])`. This is how it should work.

However, if you instead click "continue" after the first browser statement and run the remaining code automatically, when you arrive at the second browser statement, "tree" will be a list of length 0. If you then type `xml_text(data[[3]])`, it turns out that the text inside the node has been replaced by "ExampleTextAnotherPieceOfExampleText" instead of just "ExampleText". The text inside the other node (the node named "titel") is appended to it.

So for some reason, this code behaves differently depending on whether I run it manually or it's run automatically. Can anyone help me understand why this happens, and how I can solve this behavior?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sounds like a bug.. Maybe submit as an issue https://github.com/r-lib/xml2/issues

Answer (score 0):

The xml_text function returns all of the text in the parent and all of the leaf nodes, that is why some of nodes are merged values.  It does seem to be inconsistent behavior.

My suggestion as opposed to trying to operate on each node and replace the text, perform a global replacement on the entire xml document with str_replace_all and then re-read the data back as xml.

```
# XML example
exampleXML<-"<dossier>
<dossiernummer>
<dossiernr>ExampleText</dossiernr>
</dossiernummer>
<titel>AnotherPieceOfExampleText</titel>
</dossier>"

data<-read_xml(exampleXML)

data<-str_replace_all(data, "[:space:]", " ")

data<-read_xml(data)
```